# How to check for an empty set when using Perl DBI->MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Is there a way to check if a DBI->execute statement returns an empty set? The purpose is that I want to create a table, and then ask for username, if the username isn't in the table, (check for empty fetch() statement), then add to table. Any suggestions?

```
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name_here");
    $sth->execute();

    if(...$sth->fetch() was empty...)
    do something...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that :

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name_here");
$sth->execute();

unless ($sth->fetch()) { do something..; }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to check if a DBI->execute statement returns an empty set

Yes.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name_here");
$sth->execute();
unless( $sth->rows ) {
    #empty set
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `SELECT` statements. From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI) of the 'DBI' module: *"For 'SELECT' statements, it is generally not possible to know how many rows will be returned except by fetching them all"*

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you do a preliminary fetch of the number of records, like this

```
my ($records) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT count(*) FROM table_name_here');
```

Comment: will this tell me how many different entries that will return? So if I had 4 entries in a table, this would set $records = 4?

Comment: It will tell you how many records are in the table, whether or not they are different (although you will more than likely have at least one unique column, in which case they must all be different). I suggest you experiment. Bear in mind that there is a *very* slim chance that the number of records changes between you fetching the count and fetching the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach to do that:

```
my $row_count = 0;
while (my @ary = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) { ...; $row_count++; }
unless ($row_count) { 
  ...
}
```

But I can't help wondering why do you need to use `fetchrow`, and not `fetchall`, for this specific case. In fact, I'd reorganize it this way:

```
my ($count) = $dbh->selectrow_array('
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ?'
   undef, $username);
if ($count) { ... }
```